# ElasticSearch cannot find newly written document

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

In my logic, application writes documents into elasticsearch and it sometimes tries to read it from another thread. But when it tries to read it, query is not returning any hits.

I assume that in POST request (insertion), when I get 201 , it means the document is created.

Is my assumption wrong? What am I missing in here?

Thx for your responses

Neron

EDIT:

save response `{“_index”:“customers”,“_type”:“customers”,“_id”:“123",“_version”:1,“result”:“created”,“_shards”:{“total”:2,“successful”:2,“failed”:0},“created”:true}`

query request:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "id": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

query-response:

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

after some time, it gets the response and hits is not now then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing **GET** request, that's why getting `200` status code. If it is **POST** call then it should be `201` status code.

Try this query.

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "_id": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thx for the response but I think this not the case. Insertion is not the problem but I think when I get the success response, I should also be able to query it and get it. But it does not happen

Comment: Can you share one record from elasticsearch when you do GET and also share your query which you are trying

Answer (score 0):

The query request seems to be not correct. You should try "_id" instead of "id":

```
    {
     "size": 1,
     "from": 0,
     "query": {
              "bool": {
                       "must": [
                                {
                                 "match_phrase": {
                                 "_id": "123"
                                    }
                                }
                               ]
                     }
             }
    }
```